# AddSingleton - Create on run application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, asp.net-core-3.0

I need to create singletons when the application starts. In this example, I create an instance of IdentityOptions with new values. The problem is that when I start the application and I want to create a new user, it is not taking the value 125 (it keeps using 6, which is the default), but if I modify that value from a controller (see example), everything works perfectly. I understand that the instance is created at the first request, but is it possible to create it when starting the application? Because my idea is to load those values from a database.

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...

    serviceCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    ...
    ...
    ...

    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
    {
        //using (var currentContext = serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyIdentityDatabaseContext>())
        {
            return new IdentityOptions
            {
                Password = new PasswordOptions
                {
                    RequiredLength = 125
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

*Example*

```
public class TestController : BaseController<TestController>
{
    private readonly IOptions<IdentityOptions> _myOptions;

    public TestController(IOptions<IdentityOptions> myOptions)
    {
        _myOptions = myOptions;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TestConfigureOptions")]
    public IActionResult TestConfigureOptions()
    {
        // 1 - Before assigning 124, the value it has is 6. WHY?

        _myOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 124;

        // 2 - After assigning the 124 and trying to create a user with an incorrect password length, I am informed that the minimum is 124, that this is correct.

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those are two separate registrations.

`AddIdentity` would have added `IdentityOptions` via options using `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(...)`

Which would allow `IOptions<IdentityOptions>` to be injected as expected.

The second registration

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => { 

        return new IdentityOptions {
            Password = new PasswordOptions {
                RequiredLength = 125
            }
        };

});
```

has nothing to do with options.

If you would like to change the defaults then update the configuration.

```
serviceCollection.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 125;
});
```

There is also an overload for when calling `AddIdentity` to do it in one go

```
serviceCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => {
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 125;
})
```